# Add-Content command changes the content I want to add

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a file that caontains the date int its head, and after that all the process of the computer are shown. Here is my code:

```
$line = DESKTOP-790P42N
New-Item c:\check\$line -Type Directory
Get-Date -Format d | Out-File c:\chek\$line\log.txt
Add-Content c:\check\$line\log.txt (Get-Process -ComputerName $line | Select-Object ID, ProcessName)
```

I expect the result to be:

```
1/12/2017
  Id ProcessName
  -- -----------
4064 AdminService
4132 AppleMobileDeviceService
13300 ApplicationFrameHost
4288 audiodg
```

But I got this:

```
01/12/2017
@{Id=4064; ProcessName=AdminService}
@{Id=4132; ProcessName=AppleMobileDeviceService}
@{Id=13300; ProcessName=ApplicationFrameHost}
```

The weird thing is when I use these commands (Get-Date, Get-Process) into two different files, it works fine.

Comment: You're not expanding the property so you're only getting default `.ToString()` method calls for `PSCustomObject`

Comment: `Get-Process ... | Select-Object ... | Format-Table | Out-String`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You can cut out that `Select` statement and just pass `-Property` to `FT`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 True.